# Scraping a table from asp.net page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image]the page source from a asp.net page is as shown below:

```
<table class="tbl dentry1" style="margin-top:2vh;">   
                  <tr>
                    <td>Conv - A&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tha" type="text" value="6" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tha" /></td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$la" type="text" value="49" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_la" /></td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ta" type="text" value="49" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ta" /></td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tta" type="text" value="7.30" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tta" /></td>
                    <td>Mixer-1</td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$mb1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mb1" /></td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ml1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ml1" /></td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$mr1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mr1" /></td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$mc1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mc1" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>Conv - B&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$thb" type="text" value="6" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_thb" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lb" type="text" value="793" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lb" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tb" type="text" value="58" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tb" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ttb" type="text" value="6.30" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ttb" /></td>
                <td>Mixer-2</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$mb2" type="text" value="114" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mb2" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ml2" type="text" value="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ml2" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$mr2" type="text" value="136" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mr2" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$mc2" type="text" value="136" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mc2" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Conv - C&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$thc" type="text" value="4" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_thc" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lc" type="text" value="1583" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lc" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tc" type="text" value="9" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tc" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ttc" type="text" value="11.00" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ttc" /></td>
                <td colspan="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="text-align:center;">
                <td></td>
                <td>Poured</td>
                <td>Waiting</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Poured</td>
                <td>Waiting</td>
                <td>Tonnnage</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Loads</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lp" type="text" value="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lp" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lw" type="text" value="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lw" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Torpedos&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tp" type="text" value="8" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tp" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tw" type="text" value="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tw" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tt" type="text" value="2407" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tt" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Slag Yard Trips</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$syt" type="text" value="21" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_syt" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    Lance Jam Cut
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ljc" type="text" value="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ljc" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="text-align:center;">
                <td></td>
                <td>Received</td>
                <td>Consumed</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Used</td>
                <td>Successful</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Scrap</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$sr" type="text" value="323" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_sr" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$sc" type="text" value="192" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_sc" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Dart&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$du" type="text" value="8" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_du" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ds" type="text" value="7" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ds" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="10">Bin Position</th>
            </tr>

            <tr style="text-align:center;">
                <td></td>
                <td>Bin 1</td>
                <td>Bin 2</td>
                <td>Bin 3</td>
                <td>Bin 4</td>
                <td>Bin 5</td>
                <td>Bin 6</td>
                <td>Bin 7</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Conv - A&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b1a" type="text" value="15" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b1a" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b2a" type="text" value="10" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b2a" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b3a" type="text" value="45" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b3a" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b4a" type="text" value="10" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b4a" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b5a" type="text" value="50" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b5a" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b6a" type="text" value="25" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b6a" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b7a" type="text" value="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b7a" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Conv - B&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b1b" type="text" value="10" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b1b" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b2b" type="text" value="5" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b2b" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b3b" type="text" value="40" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b3b" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b4b" type="text" value="10" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b4b" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b5b" type="text" value="60" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b5b" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b6b" type="text" value="15" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b6b" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b7b" type="text" value="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b7b" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Conv - C&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b1c" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b1c" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b2c" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b2c" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b3c" type="text" value="50" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b3c" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b4c" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b4c" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b5c" type="text" value="45" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b5c" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b6c" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b6c" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b7c" type="text" value="35" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b7c" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Lime</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lime" type="text" value="155" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lime" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Dolo</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dolo" type="text" value="55" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dolo" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Ore</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ore" type="text" value="40" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ore" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Coke</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$coke" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_coke" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Raw Dolo</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rdolo" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdolo" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Heats Recovered</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hr" type="text" value="16" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hr" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">Amount Recovered</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ar" type="text" value="235000" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ar" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">Amount Export</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ae" type="text" value="235000" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ae" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Holder Level</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hl" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hl" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">Conv-C Recovery</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ccr" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ccr" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Jam Pot Received</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$jpr" type="text" value="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_jpr" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">Clear Pot Sent</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cps" type="text" value="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cps" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">Ram Tree</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rt" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rt" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>

        <table class="tbl dentry1" style="margin-top:2vh;">
            <caption>Delays & Injuries</caption>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" style="background-color:#09236b; color:#fff;">Delays</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>Delay Time</th>
                <th>Agency</th>
                <th>Details</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt1" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da1" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd1" type="text" value="LMB" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd1" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt2" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt2" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da2" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da2" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd2" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd2" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt3" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt3" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da3" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da3" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd3" type="text" value="Lime- 120 T       LHF=8.5 T       Dolo=62      I/O=  33T       LD Slag R=20         C=43 T" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd3" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt4" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt4" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da4" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da4" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd4" type="text" value="Si= 0.61       Basicity=  2.55        MgO= 12.64       SiO2=17.31" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd4" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt5" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt5" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da5" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da5" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd5" type="text" value="DS=0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd5" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt6" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt6" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da6" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da6" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd6" type="text" value="A=  1335-3.90/1.33       B=  1373-1.83/2.33         C=1320-1.37/0.99" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd6" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt7" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt7" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da7" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da7" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd7" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd7" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" style="background-color:#09236b; color:#fff;">Injuries</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Name</th>
                <th>Details</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$in1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_in1" style="width:10vw;" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$id1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_id1" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$in2" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_in2" style="width:10vw;" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$id2" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_id2" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$in3" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_in3" style="width:10vw;" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$id3" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_id3" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" style="height:10.5vh;"><input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$db_operation" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_db_operation" value="update" />
                </th>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

i need to extract the values from each of the cells. some of them may be blank.

the code i have tried is as follows:

```
table = soup.find('table',{'class':'tbl dentry1'})
data = []
table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

l = []
for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [tr.text for tr in td]
    l.append(row)

print(l)
```

but it is printing only :

> [[], [], ['Conv - A\xa0', '', '', '', '', 'Mixer-1', '', '', '', ''],
> ['Conv - B\xa0', '', '', '', '', 'Mixer-2', '', '', '', ''], ['Conv -
> C\xa0', '', '', '', '', '\xa0\xa0'], ['', 'Poured', 'Waiting', '', '',
> '', 'Poured', 'Waiting', 'Tonnnage', ''], ['Loads', '', '', '', '',
> 'Torpedos\xa0', '', '', '', ''], ['Slag Yard Trips', '', '', '', '',
> '\r\n                        Lance Jam Cut\r\n
> \n', '', ''], ['', 'Received', 'Consumed', '', '', '', 'Used',
> 'Successful', '', ''], ['Scrap', '', '', '', '', 'Dart\xa0', '', '',
> '', ''], [], ['', 'Bin 1', 'Bin 2', 'Bin 3', 'Bin 4', 'Bin 5', 'Bin
> 6', 'Bin 7', '', ''], ['Conv - A\xa0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '',
> ''], ['Conv - B\xa0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['Conv -
> C\xa0', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['Lime', '', 'Dolo', '',
> 'Ore', '', 'Coke', '', 'Raw Dolo', ''], ['Heats Recovered', '',
> 'Amount Recovered', '', 'Amount Export', '', '', ''], ['Holder Level',
> '', 'Conv-C Recovery', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ['Jam Pot Received',
> '', 'Clear Pot Sent', '', 'Ram Tree', '', '', '']]

where can i go wrong?

Comment: the text is being loaded dynamically, use Selenium to wait for the page to load and then scrape

Comment: Mind sharing the URL?

Comment: can you post a minimal version of that table and the output you expect from it

Comment: @chase the table is uploaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd
html = """
<table class="tbl dentry1" style="margin-top:2vh;">   
                  <tr>
                    <td>Conv - A&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tha" type="text" value="6" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tha" /></td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$la" type="text" value="49" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_la" /></td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ta" type="text" value="49" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ta" /></td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tta" type="text" value="7.30" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tta" /></td>
                    <td>Mixer-1</td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$mb1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mb1" /></td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ml1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ml1" /></td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$mr1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mr1" /></td>
                    <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$mc1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mc1" /></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                <td>Conv - B&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$thb" type="text" value="6" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_thb" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lb" type="text" value="793" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lb" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tb" type="text" value="58" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tb" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ttb" type="text" value="6.30" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ttb" /></td>
                <td>Mixer-2</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$mb2" type="text" value="114" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mb2" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ml2" type="text" value="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ml2" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$mr2" type="text" value="136" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mr2" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$mc2" type="text" value="136" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_mc2" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Conv - C&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$thc" type="text" value="4" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_thc" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lc" type="text" value="1583" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lc" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tc" type="text" value="9" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tc" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ttc" type="text" value="11.00" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ttc" /></td>
                <td colspan="5">&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="text-align:center;">
                <td></td>
                <td>Poured</td>
                <td>Waiting</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Poured</td>
                <td>Waiting</td>
                <td>Tonnnage</td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Loads</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lp" type="text" value="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lp" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lw" type="text" value="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lw" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Torpedos&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tp" type="text" value="8" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tp" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tw" type="text" value="1" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tw" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$tt" type="text" value="2407" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_tt" /></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Slag Yard Trips</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$syt" type="text" value="21" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_syt" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td colspan="3">
                    Lance Jam Cut
                    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ljc" type="text" value="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ljc" />
                </td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr style="text-align:center;">
                <td></td>
                <td>Received</td>
                <td>Consumed</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Used</td>
                <td>Successful</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Scrap</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$sr" type="text" value="323" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_sr" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$sc" type="text" value="192" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_sc" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td>Dart&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$du" type="text" value="8" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_du" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ds" type="text" value="7" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ds" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="10">Bin Position</th>
            </tr>

            <tr style="text-align:center;">
                <td></td>
                <td>Bin 1</td>
                <td>Bin 2</td>
                <td>Bin 3</td>
                <td>Bin 4</td>
                <td>Bin 5</td>
                <td>Bin 6</td>
                <td>Bin 7</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Conv - A&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b1a" type="text" value="15" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b1a" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b2a" type="text" value="10" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b2a" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b3a" type="text" value="45" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b3a" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b4a" type="text" value="10" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b4a" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b5a" type="text" value="50" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b5a" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b6a" type="text" value="25" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b6a" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b7a" type="text" value="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b7a" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Conv - B&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b1b" type="text" value="10" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b1b" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b2b" type="text" value="5" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b2b" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b3b" type="text" value="40" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b3b" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b4b" type="text" value="10" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b4b" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b5b" type="text" value="60" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b5b" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b6b" type="text" value="15" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b6b" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b7b" type="text" value="0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b7b" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Conv - C&nbsp;</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b1c" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b1c" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b2c" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b2c" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b3c" type="text" value="50" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b3c" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b4c" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b4c" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b5c" type="text" value="45" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b5c" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b6c" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b6c" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$b7c" type="text" value="35" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_b7c" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Lime</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$lime" type="text" value="155" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_lime" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Dolo</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dolo" type="text" value="55" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dolo" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Ore</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ore" type="text" value="40" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ore" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Coke</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$coke" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_coke" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Raw Dolo</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rdolo" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rdolo" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Heats Recovered</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hr" type="text" value="16" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hr" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">Amount Recovered</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ar" type="text" value="235000" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ar" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">Amount Export</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ae" type="text" value="235000" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ae" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Holder Level</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$hl" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_hl" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">Conv-C Recovery</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ccr" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ccr" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>Jam Pot Received</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$jpr" type="text" value="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_jpr" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">Clear Pot Sent</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$cps" type="text" value="2" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_cps" /></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;" colspan="2">Ram Tree</td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$rt" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_rt" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            
        </table>

        <table class="tbl dentry1" style="margin-top:2vh;">
            <caption>Delays & Injuries</caption>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" style="background-color:#09236b; color:#fff;">Delays</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th>Delay Time</th>
                <th>Agency</th>
                <th>Details</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt1" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da1" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd1" type="text" value="LMB" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd1" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt2" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt2" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da2" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da2" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd2" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd2" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt3" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt3" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da3" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da3" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd3" type="text" value="Lime- 120 T       LHF=8.5 T       Dolo=62      I/O=  33T       LD Slag R=20         C=43 T" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd3" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt4" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt4" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da4" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da4" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd4" type="text" value="Si= 0.61       Basicity=  2.55        MgO= 12.64       SiO2=17.31" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd4" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt5" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt5" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da5" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da5" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd5" type="text" value="DS=0" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd5" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt6" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt6" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da6" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da6" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd6" type="text" value="A=  1335-3.90/1.33       B=  1373-1.83/2.33         C=1320-1.37/0.99" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd6" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dt7" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dt7" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$da7" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_da7" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$dd7" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_dd7" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="3">&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" style="background-color:#09236b; color:#fff;">Injuries</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="2">Name</th>
                <th>Details</th>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$in1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_in1" style="width:10vw;" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$id1" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_id1" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$in2" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_in2" style="width:10vw;" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$id2" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_id2" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$in3" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_in3" style="width:10vw;" /></td>
                <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$id3" type="text" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_id3" style="width:25vw;" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <th colspan="3" style="height:10.5vh;"><input type="hidden" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$db_operation" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_db_operation" value="update" />
                </th>
            </tr>

        </table>   
"""

dfs = pd.read_html(html)

dfs[0].to_csv("D:\\Table_1.csv", index = False)
```

Screenshot of `Table_1.csv`:

[image]

**Edit:**:

You can't get the `value` attribute using this method. In order to do that, you have to use `BeautifulSoup`. Here is the full code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html = "Your HTML"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

table = soup.find('table', class_ = "tbl dentry1")

tr_tags = table.find_all('tr')

final = {}
final = []
for tr in tr_tags:
    lst = []
    td_tags = tr.find_all('td')
    for td in td_tags:
        if td.input:
            if td.input.has_attr('value'):
                lst.append(td.input['value'])
        elif td.text != "":
            lst.append(td.text.replace('\xa0',''))
        else:
            lst.append('')

    for x in range(10 - len(lst)):
        lst.append("")

    final.append(lst)

columns = [f'Column {x+1}' for x in range(10)]

df = pd.DataFrame(final,columns=columns)

df.to_csv("D:\\Table_1.csv", index = False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Screenshot of `Table_1.csv`:

[image]

Comment: thanks. but how do we get the values from <td><input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$thb" type="text" value="6" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_thb" /></td>. for e.g  value= 6.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible with pandas. You have to use `BeautifulSoup` for that. What is the expected output?

Comment: ['Conv-A','6,'49','7.30','Mixer-1','','','',''],['Conv-B','6','793','58','6.30','Mixer-2','114','2','136',136']... i.e print all rows

Comment: Can u type these values in a `csv`/`excel` file, take a screenshot and post it in ur question? So that I can understand the required format.

Comment: @bipin_s Did my answer help u?

Comment: @bipin_s Plsss reply.

Comment: YW! If my ans has helped u, pls upvote my ans and accept it as the best ans. Thanks!